# Locus given by a pair of scissors sliding along the ground.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

I came up with this problem when dragging a pair of scissors along the ground. The question is, more mathematically:

Suppose there is a point $(a,0)$ and a point $(0,b)$ with a fixed distance $m$ between them. And suppose there is a point $(x,y)$ that  lies along the line that intersects both $(a,0)$ and $(0,b)$ but is always a distance $n$ from $(0,b)$, and $n+k$ from $(a,0)$, for some $k$. Express $y$ in terms of $m$, $n$ and $x$ (or alternatively, $x$ in terms of $m$, $n$ and $y$)

So far I have:

$\frac{b-y}{x} = \frac{b}{a} = \frac{y}{a-x}$ by the respective gradients of lines connecting each point being equal.

$(b-y)^2+x^2=n^2$ , $b^2+a^2=k^2$ and $y^2+(a-x)^2=(n+k)^2$ by the distances being fixed.

$ab=ay+bx$  is the only useful information I can gather from the gradient equations.

And even when applying this to various combinations of the others I cannot seem to make any progress and just make algebraic monsters with no progress towards a coherent equation in sight. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By section formula, $x = … = \frac {na}{2n + k}$

∴ $a = \frac{(2n+k)x}{n}$

Similarly, $b = \frac{(2n + k)y}{n+k}$

By Pythagoras, $( \frac{(2n+k)x}{n})^2 +( \frac{(2n + k)y}{n+k})^2 = m^2$

I.e. $( \frac{(m)}{n})^2x^2 +( \frac{(m)}{m – n})^2y^2 = m^2$

From which, you can get the equation of the required locus.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to find points A and B goven the information, and from there, x or y could be found easily. This might be more intuitive (and really did take quite a while!) so I hope you will take a look. See the accompanying desmos for further instruction.

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fwnq8owykt

The variable m stays constant, and a and b shift accordingly. By drawing a line parallel to the X axis at the x coordinate, one can form two similar triangles, (the one in red and the one in blue). As a result, the corresponding parts of these similar triangles are in proportion.

$$\frac{m}{n} = \frac{b}{b-x}$$

$$m(b-x)=bn$$

$$mb - mx = bn$$

$$mb - bn = mx$$

$$b(m-n)=mx$$

$$b = \frac{mx}{m-n}$$

This means we can find a, too!

$$a^2 + b^2 = m^2$$

$$a^2 = m^2 - b^2$$

$$a = \sqrt{m^2 - b^2}$$

$$a = \sqrt{m^2 - \Big(\frac{mx}{m-n}\Big)^2}$$

The rest is really easy. We already have a y intercept and two points, so we can find the slope of line m by using the formula

$$slope=\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}$$

on points (a,0) and (0,b). I will substitute later to keep everything clean.

$$slope=\frac{b-0}{0-a}$$

$$=\frac{-b}{a}$$

Also, remember that point (0,b) is our y intercept, so the equation for our line m is

$$y = \frac{-b}{a}x+b$$

Now we plug stuff back in!

$$y = \frac{-\frac{mx}{m-n}}{\sqrt{m^2 - \Big(\frac{mx}{m-n}\Big)^2}}+\frac{mx}{m-n}$$

Comment: Nice. I was beginning to suspect that some algebraic beast-taming was necessary, it's good to see that it's possible.